# How to solve the following SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have five tables named [User], [UserCard], [Card], [CardType] and [Transaction].  The data stored in these tables is shown respectively from top to bottom.

[image]

Now I want to run following query:

For each card type, show the total number of cards whose total sum of transaction amount is greater than 6000.
Here is the sql code for the tables and there data:

```
go

create table [User](
[userId] int primary key,
[name] varchar(20) not null,
[phoneNum] varchar(15) not null,
[city] varchar(20) not null
)
go

create table CardType(
[cardTypeID] int primary key,
[name] varchar(15),
[description] varchar(40) null
)
go
create Table [Card](
cardNum Varchar(20) primary key,
cardTypeID int foreign key references  CardType([cardTypeID]),
PIN varchar(4) not null,
[expireDate] date not null,
balance float not null
)
go


Create table UserCard(
userID int foreign key references [User]([userId]),
cardNum varchar(20) foreign key references [Card](cardNum),
primary key(cardNum)
)
go
create table [Transaction](
transId int primary key,
transDate date not null,
cardNum varchar(20) foreign key references [Card](cardNum),
amount int not null
)


INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (1, N'Ali', N'03036067000', N'Narowal')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (2, N'Ahmed', N'03036047000', N'Lahore')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (3, N'Aqeel', N'03036063000', N'Karachi')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (4, N'Usman', N'03036062000', N'Sialkot')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([userId], [name], [phoneNum], [city]) VALUES (5, N'Hafeez', N'03036061000', N'Lahore')
GO


INSERT [dbo].[CardType] ([cardTypeID], [name], [description]) VALUES (1, N'Debit', N'Spend Now, Pay Now')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CardType] ([cardTypeID], [name], [description]) VALUES (2, N'Credit', N'Spend Now, Pay later')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1234', 1, N'1770', CAST(N'2022-07-01' AS Date), 43025.31)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1235', 1, N'9234', CAST(N'2020-03-02' AS Date), 14425.62)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1236', 1, N'1234', CAST(N'2019-02-06' AS Date), 34325.52)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1237', 2, N'1200', CAST(N'2021-02-05' AS Date), 24325.3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Card] ([cardNum], [cardTypeID], [PIN], [expireDate], [balance]) VALUES (N'1238', 2, N'9004', CAST(N'2020-09-02' AS Date), 34025.12)
GO

INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (1, N'1234')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (1, N'1235')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (2, N'1236')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (3, N'1238')
GO
Insert  [dbo].[UserCard] ([userID], [cardNum]) VALUES (4, N'1237')

INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-02-02' AS Date), N'1234', 500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-02-03' AS Date), N'1235', 3000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2017-05-06' AS Date), N'1236', 2500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2016-09-09' AS Date), N'1238', 2000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Transaction] ([transId], [transDate], [cardNum], [amount]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2015-02-10' AS Date), N'1234', 6000)
GO


Select * from [User]
Select * from UserCard
Select * from [Card]
Select * from CardType
Select * from [Transaction]
```

I am allowed to use the joining functions, aggregate functions and grouping functions. I have tried several queries but am not able to get the expected output. The expected output is shown here.

[image]

The reason for this expected output is that there is only one debit card with card number 1234 on which a transaction of more than 6000 has been done. And there is no credit card on which a transaction of more than 6000 has been done. 
Please guide me what will be the query to get the expected output.
Thanks.

Comment: You do not have a transaction of more than 6000 in the transaction table. So you need to clarify your problem statement. Also, it is not advisable to have table names like user and transaction.

Comment: Yes there is no single transaction of more than 6000 but the user with card number 1234(i.e. Ali) has collectively done transactions of 6000+500=6500. So, the expected output image I attached, shows that there is one debit card on which a transaction of more than 6000 has been done. And there are 0 credit cards on which a transaction of more than 6000 has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing a sub-query and a group-by can't fix!

Enjoy :)

```
select 
    ct.cardTypeID,
    ct.name,
    count (distinct cardNum) as '#OfCards'

from [cardType] ct
left join 
    (select 
        c.cardNum,
        ct.cardTypeID,
        ct.name
    from [card] c
    join [cardType] ct on c.cardTypeID = ct.cardTypeID

    where c.cardNum in
        (select 
            cardNum
        from [transaction]
        group by cardNum
        having sum(amount) > 6000)
) sq on sq.cardTypeID = ct.cardTypeID and sq.name = ct.name

group by    
    ct.cardTypeID,
    ct.name
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
select t1.cardTypeID, t1.name,
    ISNULL((
    select count(distinct t2.cardNum)
    from Card t2
    join Transactions t3 on t3.cardNum = t2.cardNum
    where t2.cardTypeID = t1.cardTypeID
    group by t2.cardNum
    having sum(t3.amount) > 6000
    ), 0) as NumberOfCards
from CardType t1
group by t1.cardTypeID, t1.name
```

Comment: This gets the right answer but possibly for the wrong reason - I don't think you should be selecting cardTypeID as the number of cards! Imagine the cardTypeID wasn't 1's and 2's but alphas instead this query won't work. :)

Comment: @MarkTaylor Thank you for pointing that out. I have made the change.